# Bind the event handlers datetimepicker on input after div reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the datetimepicker jQuery that i used on my project inside a `$(document).ready(function () {});`

```
//Set datetimepicker jquery
$('.dateStartTechPicker').datetimepicker({
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
});
```

The problem is that when i reload the div that contains this inputs datetime value with the function:

```
$('#technicians_div').load(window.location + " #technicians_div>*", "");
```

Only that div get updated with new date and time, but i click again the button that show the input with datetimepicker selector the widget is not showed.

I know that the .on(action, selector, funciton) keep the event handler after reload, but don't know how applicate this in my case.

I need to reset the event on input with .datetimepicker after div reloading.

How can i handle this?

I try something like this without results:

```
$('#technicians_div').load(window.location + " #technicians_div>*", "");
//Set again after load datetimepicker jquery
$('.dateStartTechPicker').datetimepicker({
     format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
});
```

**EDIT**

I reload the div that contain all technicians elements so all added css rule are cleared, and stored readonly values come back.

[image: div that i reload]

How manipulate the success of
`$('#technicians_div').load(window.location + " #technicians_div>*", "");`?

Comment: are you reloading div or element by ajax?
if so then you have to reinitialize datepicker on success call back of ajax

Comment: @UttamUghareja edit post.
I'm reloading div that contain all elements.
How can i reinitialize datepicke in on success call back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#technicians_div').load(window.location + " #technicians_div>*", function(){
  $('.dateStartTechPicker').datetimepicker({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
   });
});
```

you are initializing it before ajax complete, datepicker needed to be initialize on success call back of ajax outside 
 initialize date picker on load callback.

Comment: i don't know that was possible call a function after .load()
Thanks for the suggestion.